# Advice on SSO solution for cross platform and domain sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth, wif

I feel a bit overwhelmed right now with how to approach building an SSO solution for a project I'm taking on.  I understand that I need a centralized login site, but, I'd like input on what framework I should be using to achieve this.  I've been reading a bit about Windows Identity Foundation (WIF), but, the lack of documentation and code samples is quite disappointing.  DotNotOpenAuth sounds like it has much more usage by the community than WIF, but, I'm not sure if that's the right framework for me to use given that I am not going to be letting third-party accounts be used for logging in.

There are multiple user data stores to take into account as well; active directory and a SQL Server database.

I really don't care what framework I use so long as it's simple and intuitive; I don't want an overly complex solution.  Documentation and samples are also a plus!  I already have experience with creating custom role providers and membership providers; those were a breeze and easy to do.

Here is a very quick visual of the structure I'm dealing with:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this post belongs here, but anyway, I've worked on a similar problem in the past and we used http://asproxy.sourceforge.net/ as base

Comment: How can a proxy help here?

Answer (score 1):

Refer: [Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) and [Identity Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14347). There's WIF samples there.

In terms of what you want to achieve, ADFS v2.0 will get you most of the way but it can only authenticate against AD. For SQL server, use [IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.com/) and then federate ADFS and IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SAML.  It is designed to address SSO.  You may also want to look into OpenID.

There are enterprise products out there, such as CA Site Minder or IBM Tivoli for this kind if thing.  They are not cheap because building a custom solution for this will be quite a feat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are .NET based - then .NET 4.5 (which includes WIF) is the way to go.

But the framework will be you simplest problem. Building that kind of security infrastructure is hard. Have a look at both the book and idenitity server from nzpcmad's answer as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as cross-platform goes, [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saml) tends to lead the pack.  There are many implementations (java, php, perl).  As Dominick (@leastprivilege) mentioned, if every application is .Net based, WS-Fed via [WIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Identity_Foundation) is the way to go.  (btw, Dominick is **the man** when it comes to WIF - definitely hit his blog and forums up if you plan on exploring that route)

OpenId and OAuth are alternatives that you will hear about.  They are somewhat less secure (the trust is in the user, rather than the infrastructure) and you will find that you will have to build a provider in order to support sign-in using your own user store.

Regardless of the route you choose, be prepared to do a lot of reading and learning.  Check out the wikipedia articles above for a nice overview of how these technologies work, and don't be afraid to ask questions..